# Setting up a page to house certain types of posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, admin-menu

I have recently taken over this company's website operations and I am trying to set up a page to house a certain type of post. The previous webmaster has already done this before but I can't figure out how to do it again.

Here is a picture to help describe what I'm trying to do.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw0e4.jpg

I want to make a sub-section of posts with the title **reports/presentations** the same way that it has past webinars, product links, and current webinars. Ideally, this reports/presentations piece will only be available to members. I just don't get how to do it, it's like they are a completely separate entity, not just a category of post, you can post inside of those areas without your post showing up on the overall **posts** menu.

Comment: Those are custom post types, but you'll need to clarify some more, e.g. by members do you mean logged in users? Or are you referring to a membership plugin? Do you mean only available to members on the frontend? Only available in the admin screen?

Comment: Members via membership plugin. I've got that all figured out and pretty much set up though I think. Some of our customers pay to be a member of the site, and they will be receiving this reports tab.

Answer (score 0):

Create you own [WP_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)  running on this post type out side the main loop.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'cpt_name');
$cptq = new WP_query($args);
if($cptq->have_posts()):
while($cptq->have_posts()):$cptq->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Comment: I apologize for being a WP noob, but I can't quite figure out where to access this php file in order to put the code block you have provided into it.

Comment: you have a page template, we'll call it cpt-page.php
the basic structur of a page is:

Comment: you have a page template, we'll call it cpt-page.php
the basic structure of a page is:  is this https://pastebin.com/j4BxhNEy, this is for cpt: https://pastebin.com/iGxNbLbK

Comment: Sorry, what is cpt? and this is what my template.php should look like?

Comment: cpt = custom post type.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: So your first link would be for if I didn't have custom post types, but the second link is because I do have cpts, the commented out section is from your original post. So I need to make a template.php file in my theme and c+p the second link in there. What do I need to fill out in it myself?

Comment: Basically yes. Also look at WordPress's documentation for further information and best practices.